# How to embed a YouTube playlist in hugo website

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I can make use of the following code, `{{< youtube hvWSg6NblSU >}}` to embed the YouTube video in hugo website, where hvWSg6NblSU is the value in following url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvWSg6NblSU

Instead of embedding a single video, I want to embed the following playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDe3_HhjV1foHQbtGpdo0FSmsMrVykuKJ

**Question**: Is there a way I can embed the above playlist. Basically I am trying to make a page using hugo which will show the playlist on YouTube.

In the following link: https://naresh-chaurasia.github.io/talk2naresh/course/python-kids/, I have a single YouTube video but want to add link to entire playlist using hugo. Is it possible.

Although I can create a hyperlink to the playlist, but I want to display the YouTube playlist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not supported by the built-in youtube shortcode.

What you can do is create a new youtube shortcode for playlists.

### Steps

1. Create: `/layouts/shortcodes/youtubepl.html`
2. In that file place  the following: (based on the [built-in youtube shortcode](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/tpl/tplimpl/embedded/templates/shortcodes/youtube.html))

```html
{{- $pc := .Page.Site.Config.Privacy.YouTube -}}
{{- if not $pc.Disable -}}
{{- $ytHost := cond $pc.PrivacyEnhanced  "www.youtube-nocookie.com" "www.youtube.com" -}}
{{- $id := .Get "id" | default (.Get 0) -}}
{{- $class := .Get "class" | default (.Get 1) -}}
{{- $title := .Get "title" | default "YouTube Video" }}
<div {{ with $class }}class="{{ . }}"{{ else }}style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"{{ end }}>
  <iframe src="https://{{ $ytHost }}/embed/videoseries?list={{ $id }}{{ with .Get "autoplay" }}{{ if eq . "true" }}&autoplay=1{{ end }}{{ end }}" {{ if not $class }}style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; border:0;" {{ end }}allowfullscreen title="{{ $title }}"></iframe>
</div>
{{ end -}}
```

(aside: If you prefer to have a different shortcode name, simply change the filename. For example, if you prefer to use `{{< ytplaylist >}}` change the shortcode filename to `ytplaylist.html`.)

### Usage

- Usage is the same as the built-in `{{< youtube >}}` shortcode, just use the new shortcode name like so: `{{< youtubepl id="ID-HERE" >}}` or `{{< youtubepl ID-HERE >}}`.
- Instead of the video ID, you'll use the playlist ID.

Comment: I have checked in the code here: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/nareshchaurasia-talk2naresh-code-git. As per above, I have added `youtubepl.html` in location `layouts\shortcodes` and `themes\hugo-theme-relearn\layouts\shortcodes`. I have also created content\basics\poc.md using `{{< youtubepl id="PLDe3_HhjV1foHQbtGpdo0FSmsMrVykuKJ" >}}`, but it is not working. Am I doing something wrong, since this code is not working.

Comment: Hi, I checked your git repo but the youtubepl shortcode file is empty. In any case, I pulled your repo and tested on my end; with the above code, it appears to be working, see screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/ndhNxu8t2leN.png. The code in poc.md is also correct.

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine for me now. I forgot to checkin the code in git. I made changes suggested by you and it works fine.